# Access 2013: Disabled Mode

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am having a great deal of difficulty identifying the source a problem I am having with "disabled mode" in MS Access 2013. I have read all of the support literature for 2007, 2010, and 2013 pertaining, and none of it is productive in solving the issue.

When I go to perform any sort of modification query in one of my database files I get the "The action or event has been blocked by Disabled Mode" message at the bottom bar. There is no message bar that comes up and asks me if I want to enable the content, despite this option being checked in the trust center. I have also tried going into the File>info backstage view, however, there is no "enable" button here either as reported in the 2013 help document.

Possibly the most telling characteristic of this problem is that it is not manifested in the original database of which the current database is an exact copy. I'm not sure what to make of this though.

Answer (score 0):

Enable database content for a session

To enable database content for a session, you use the Message Bar.

The Message Bar

The Message Bar appears just under the Ribbon, and is part of the Microsoft Office Fluent User Interface. If the Message Bar is not visible, you must first show the message bar. In some cases, you will also have to enable the Message Bar. Once the Message Bar is visible and enabled, you can use it to enable database content for a session.

Step 1: Show the Message Bar

If the Message Bar is already visible, you can skip this step.

On the Database Tools tab, in the Show/Hide group, select the Message Bar check box.

If the Message Bar check box is disabled, you will have to enable it.

Step 2: Enable the Message Bar

If the Message Bar check box is enabled, you can skip this step.

1.Click the Microsoft Office Button Office button image, and then click Access Options.

2.In the left pane of the Access Options dialog box, click Trust Center.

3.In the right pane, under Microsoft Office Access Trust Center, click Trust Center Settings.

4.In the left pane of the Trust Center dialog box, click Message Bar.

5.In the right pane, click Show the Message Bar in all applications when content has been blocked, and then click OK.

6.Close and reopen the database to apply the changed setting.

Step 3: Enable database content for a session

1.In the Message Bar, click Options.

2.In the Microsoft Office Security Options dialog box, click Enable this content, and then click OK.

Top of Page

Enable a database by default

To specify that a given database is trustworthy and should be enabled by default, make sure that the database file is located in a trusted location. A trusted location is a folder or file path on your computer or a location on your intranet from which it is considered safe to run code. Default trusted locations include the Templates, AddIns, and Startup folders. You can also specify your own trusted locations.

Tip   If you want to know the path of the current database, click the Microsoft Office Button, click Manage, and then click Database Properties. The full path of the current database's location is listed on the General tab of the Database Properties dialog box.

Move a database file to a trusted location

Open the folder where the database file is currently located, and then copy the database file into the trusted location that you want.

Specify a trusted location

1.In the Message Bar, click Options.

2.At the bottom of the Microsoft Office Security Options dialog box, click Open the Trust Center.

3.In the left pane of the Trust Center dialog box, click Trusted Locations.

4.To add a network location, in the right pane, select the Allow Trusted Locations on my network check box.

5.Click Add new location.

6.In the Microsoft Office Trusted Location dialog box, do one of the following:

In the Path box, type the full path of the location that you want to add.

Click Browse to browse to the location.

7.To specify that subfolders of the new trusted locations should also be trusted, select the Subfolders of this location are also trusted check box.

8.Optionally, in the Description box, type a description for the trusted location.